# Label foreground resource

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, label, foreground

I've got a small WPF issue here that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to set up a `ResourceDictionary` containing a number of colors, brushes and `ControlTemplate` entries.

My problem is that I'm trying the set the foreground brush of a `Label` to a resource in the same file and that bit isn't working and there's no trace messages about it.

```
<Color x:Shared="false" x:Key="DefaultForegroundColor" A="255" R="0" G="0" B="0" />
<!--<Color x:Shared="false" x:Key="DefaultForegroundColor" A="255" R="255" G="0" B="0" />-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Shared="false" x:Key="DefaultForegroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource DefaultForegroundColor}"/>

<Color x:Shared="false" x:Key="HeadingColor" A="255" R="17" G="158" B="218" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Shared="false" x:Key="HeadingBrush" Color="{DynamicResource HeadingColor}"/>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="SectionHeadingStyle">
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HeadingBrush}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource DefaultForegroundBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
               <ContentPresenter Margin="5"/>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

The border colour works fine (even when it's not black) but the foreground of the label remains black instead of a light blue. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Forgot to mention that it looks good in the designer too.

**UPDATE 2**
Upon Snooping the Visual Tree it appears that the `Foreground` colour makes it most of way through the template until the `ContentPresenter` uses a `TextBlock` to display the header text. The `TextBlock` remains black while the ContentPresenter above has a nice shade of blue  set to `TextElement.Foreground`. Is there something else I can do in the Template to give the created `TextBlock` the foreground colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realised I never closed this question:

In the end there was a library importing resources at application level. For some reason these caused a conflict with my resources and neither were applied. Moving the library's resources to Window or UserControl level fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible solutions

you need to make the resource a `StaticResource`.  For example, if you change the brush to this it works:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Shared="false" x:Key="HeadingBrush" Color="{StaticResource HeadingColor}"/>
```

Or if you change the Foreground in the style to a `StaticResource`, it will work.

The other option is to remove the `x:Shared="false"` from both the brush and the color.  That resolves the issue also.

```
<Color x:Key="HeadingColor" A="255" R="17" G="158" B="218" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeadingBrush" Color="{DynamicResource HeadingColor}"/>
```

It seems to be an issue with the combination of multiple layers of `DynamicResource` plus the non-shared resources.

Comment: Hi Brian. I had previously changed the code from your suggested form to the `x:Shared` and `DynamicResource` version I posted following another (incorrect) blog post. Unfortunately means I'm still without the desired result.

Comment: @GlacialSpoon what is your desired result?  I can understand the desire for DynamicResources (skinning or something?) but why can they not be shared?

Comment: Sorry Brian. To clarify, the desired result is the foreground colour in the style actually being applied to the label's content at runtime. The style defines `HeadingColor` as a light blue but the resulting content is always black. In my current app the content is most likely a string so I figured it would render text in the foreground colour. I'm not too fussed about the method or if it's static or dynamic or otherwise. I just can't get it to colour my text! :( Please say if this is still confusing.

Comment: So do the changes above (either changing to a `StaticResource` or removing the `x:Shared="false") not work for you?  I tested out your code and either one of these changes solved the problem for me.

Comment: No sorry, not sure what I'm doing but the foreground colour of the styled label is always black. The little underlining border thing gets the colour no problem. I'll double check the rest of the visual tree, maybe Snoop it. If it helps the problem item is part of a UserControl which then sits in the main window.